# filtering datagrid using combobox

Tags: c#-3.0

I had created a datagridview like this

```
public void gridviewsetup()
    {
      tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("1", "Empid");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("2", "Emp no");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("3", "Emp Name");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("4", "Department ");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("5", "Designation");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("6", "Shift");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("7", "Start Time");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("8", "End Time");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("9", "OT");
        tbl_Aplication.Columns.Add("10", "Reversed Swipe Out");            
        tbl_Aplication.RowTemplate.Height = 18;            
    }
```

and i had populated a data table to fill the data dgridview

```
 public void filldatagrid()
    {
        if (cmb_dept.Text.Trim() != "")
        {



Datatable employedata = empreg.getallemployeeshiftdetails(int.Parse(cmb_dept.SelectedValue.ToString()), Program.LOCTNPK);

          tbl_Aplication.Rows.Clear();
        tbl_Aplication.DataSource = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < employedata.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            tbl_Aplication.Rows.Add();
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = employedata.Rows[i][0];

            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = employedata.Rows[i][1];
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = employedata.Rows[i][2];
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = employedata.Rows[i][3];
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = employedata.Rows[i][4];
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = employedata.Rows[i][5];
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = employedata.Rows[i][6];   
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = employedata.Rows[i][7];
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value = 0;
            tbl_Aplication.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value = employedata.Rows[i][7];           


        }
    }
```

}

now i want to filter data in the datagrid with the designation selected in the combobox  without going back to database ,I did it like this but it shows error

```
   private void cmb_designation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (desgflag != 0)
        {
            if (cmb_dept.SelectedValue!=null )
            {

           // tbl_Aplication.DataSource = employedata;
                ((DataTable)tbl_Aplication.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = " designationnName like '%" + cmb_dept.Text.Trim() + "%' ";
         }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done it

```
private void cmb_department_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (cmb_department.Text.Trim() == "" || cmb_department.Text.Trim() == null)
                {

                    tbl_DestinationData.DataSource = dt;
                }

                else
                {
                    ((DataTable)tbl_DestinationData.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = " Dept like '%" + cmb_department.Text.Trim() + "%' ";

                }



            }
            catch (Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }

    }
```